# Google+ SignIn Button with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, google-plus, phonegap-plugins

How can we use the JS Google+ Signin button with Phonegap?  Specifically for iOS?
I have found [this article](http://lifehacker.com/302197/useful-command-line-tricks-for-mac-users) on doing oauth with phonegap and the childbrowser plugin however I'm not sure that approach will work with the Google+ signin button.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The Google+ Sign-In button won't work for you in PhoneGap because of how Phonegap serves content (basically its treated as file://) and that leads to a few problems that relate to either the button itself or to the API Console config.

What you'll want to do is to use an OAuth plugin for PhoneGap and treat your phonegap app as an "Installed application." I did a quick glance through the following tutorial and it appears to be an accurate set up and process:

http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery

You can still request the Google+ Sign-In scope (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`) with this approach and take advantage of most of the new Google+ features.

I will be interested to learn if you get this working, so please comment later if you are successful.

Comment: I've been working this that and have not got working yet.  Will post here if I get it up.  Nice Google Glass!

Comment: @Patrick - any success on the Oauth using Javascript? I am struggling with this yet. Kindly let me know

Comment: @LohithKrishna I did get it working, however the details I can't recall right now.  I actually moved to native app over phonegap

Comment: @Patrick - ok... so it was not possible with phonegap.. thank you for the input.. :)

Comment: Apparently ChildBrowser is retired. On their dev page, it said that PhoneGap picked up the InAppBrowser again or something to that affect (effect? awake too long, anyway). Going to give that a go: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html