# Node JS for Google Mirror API

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, oauth, google-mirror-api

I am trying to implement the Oauth using Node JS for Glass Mirror API amd [found this useful](https://github.com/emil10001/glass-mirror-nodejs-auth-demo/blob/master/app.js). In the "app.js" file, we need to provide the credentials of the project created in the Google developer console.

I have the client ID, client secret but am not able to define what should my callback URL be? What should be in the callback URL script? Logically I understand that there should be a program that accepts the token and runs the further steps.

But how to write one? kindly help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your operating environment a little better? You talk about node.js in the question, which is typically a server-side environment, but then talk about phonegap on Glass in the answer that @wayne posted, which suggests that you're writing a client-side GDK app. Since Glass itself is generally too limited to go through the auth dance (it has no keyboard - or are you using a bluetooth one?), and Google hasn't released the way for GDK apps to do auth... what are you doing?

Comment: @Prisoner - yes, that's what am trying - do an Oauth from my Google Glass phonegap app. So that I can get access to the timeline to post a timeline card.
Google hasn't released a way for GDK apps? I think they have it for Java, .NET, PHP, Python and Ruby in their official documentation.

Comment: @Prisoner - any solution for doing this Oauth from Google glass app (built using Phonegap)?

Answer (score 1):

base on the sample code from your link, the callback URL will be

```
// running in localhost
http://localhost/oauth2callback

// or running on your server
http://yourdomain.com/oauth2callback
```

when the google redirect to oauth2callback, your server code will run to redirect back to index page

```
grabToken(req.query.code, failure, function () {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need this implementation for a phonegap app installed on Google Glass to access the mirror API. Is it possible?
I saw at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109762/google-signin-button-with-phonegap - that because of the file:/// notation in phonegap, URL redirection is not possible. 
Do you have a working sample of this, if it is possible? please let me know

Comment: I never do any phonegap, however I am able to use Oauth2 for installed  app flow on chrome extension. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp. I use urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob for redirect url. basically after user login/grant, I monitor the change in browser url. you may have a try.